# Problem with using Promises in MySQL query of NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I have this line of codes in my express server in NodeJS:

```
sql = "SELECT mName FROM tokenMerchant " +
        "WHERE mUUID = ?";
        console.log("Merchant ID: ",tr.merchantId);
        pool.getConnection(function(err, conn){
            if (err) throw err;

            function getMerchantName(query){

                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
                    pool.query(query, [tr.merchantId], function(err, result){

                        if(err) return reject(err);

                        resolve(result);

                    });
                });

            };

            getMerchantName(sql).then(
                result => {
                    tr.secondaryName = result[0].mName;
                    console.log("Secondary Name: ",tr.secondaryName);
                    conn.release;
                    getUrl();
                }
            ).catch(
                error => {
                    console.log('Rejected');
                }
            );

        }); 

        function getRUrl(){//some codes here after promise resolved
}
```

And this is the output in the console:
[image]

My problem is:

1. It does not trigger the `getUrl()`
2. It will log in console the "Secondary Name" then it will also log the "rejected" which is weird because it was `resolved` and `rejected`?

Please give me idea of what's wrong with the above code. Thanks.

Comment: `conn.release` ... was that meant to be `conn.release()`?

Comment: debugging 101: try `console.log('Rejected', error);` because then you'll see the reason for the rejection - probably the (not shown) `getUrl` function throwing an error

Comment: either is working I think because it doesn't give me an error. The query is initiated but there's something wrong with the promise.

Comment: so, `console.log('Rejected', error);` doesn't give you any further help? what is the function `getUrl` - can you share it with us? ... `there's something wrong with the promise` - yes, it's rejected most likely by an error thrown in `getUrl` function

Comment: perhaps it's because your function is called `getRUrl` not `getUrl`

Comment: My bad this `getRUrl` typo thing ruined my 3 hours of life! thanks @JaromandaX.

Comment: Odd, if you `console.log(error)` in the `.catch`, it should output `ReferenceError: getUrl is not defined`